# How to check if an arbitrary PID is running using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, pid, platform-independent

Is there some way to check if an arbitrary PID is running or alive on the system, using Node.js? Assume that the Node.js script has the appropriate permissions to read `/proc` or the Windows equivalent.

This could be done either synchronously:

```
if (isAlive(pid)) { //do stuff }
```

Or asynchronously:

```
getProcessStatus(pid, function(status) {
    if (status === "alive") { //do stuff }
}
```

Note that I'm hoping to find a solution for this that works with an arbitrary system PID , *not* just the PID of a running Node.js process.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I needed to check for running pid's in a project as well. I took [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647313/how-to-check-wether-a-process-with-a-given-pid-is-running?rq=1) of using `kill -0 <PID>` and wrapped it up in a module called **is-running**  https://npmjs.org/package/is-running

`npm install is-running`

Comment: +1 Doesn't spawn a child for killing. Just a question though, why do you require the module exec in your `index.js`?

Comment: exec is left over from a previous version. It should go away

Comment: This works in simple situations, but be aware that *it will report processes don't exist if your user does not have permission to signal them*. For example, unless you are running as a root user, PID 1 (the root PID of the OS) and any system-level daemon PIDs will be reported as nonexistent.

Comment: @ZacB on macOS at least, you get EPERM if the process exists but you don't have permission, and ESRCH if it doesn't exist

Comment: I believe a clean solution (not requiring another npm module) should be selected answer.

Comment: I'm very against using an NPM package for any simple task.

Answer (score 41):

You can call `process.kill(pid, 0)` and wrap it up in a try/catch.

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal -

> "Will throw an error if target does not exist, and as a special case, a signal of 0 can be used to test for the existence of a process."

Example:

```js
function pidIsRunning(pid) {
  try {
    process.kill(pid, 0);
    return true;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: For whoever needs to hear this today: Yes, this does work on Windows, even though other uses of `process.kill` aren't always what you expect (for example, `-2` does not send a `SIGINT` on Windows -- it just kills the process)