# HapiJS start longer background process

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, hapi.js

How should I implement a `PHP exec` like call to a system function with HapiJS? The user submits a processing job that needs to run in the background for some time.

I somehow need to return a job id / session id to the user, run the job asynchronously, allow the user to check back for completion and reroute when completed...

I bet there are existing solutions for that, yet I'd highly welcome a pointer into the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Check out node's child process documentation: [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v5.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)

To do what you are describing I would spawn a process without a callback and then use a little trick: trying to kill a process that isn't running causes an error [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390930/how-to-check-if-an-arbitrary-pid-is-running-using-node-js)

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

//Launch the process
const child = exec('ls');
const pid = child.pid;

//later in another scope when you are looking to see if it is running
try {
    process.kill(pid, 0);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log("it's finished");
}
```

Comment: Cool, I will try this.